# Loading a json file into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am having a bit of trouble trying to load a JSON file into a pandas data frame. I have gone through different iterations of code listed below with no luck:

```
import pandas as pd

fileName = "ipl2015_auction_data.json"
jsonData = pd.read_json(fileName, orient="records")
```

**ERROR:** ValueError: arrays must all be same length

```
import pandas as pd

fileName = "ipl2015_auction_data.json"
#jsonData = pd.read_json(fileName, orient="records")

with open(fileName, "r") as jsonFile:
    data = jsonFile.read()

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print df.head()
```

**ERROR:** pandas.core.common.PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is the [JSON data](https://gist.github.com/Spider101/0e0cf76e6a9229cbfb4b1357668fcdb8) I am trying to load.

**SOLUTION:**

It turns out there was an issue with my pandas installation. Re-installing it did the trick.

Comment: Have you tried the first iteration without the `orient` flag? I tried `jsonData = pd.read_json("ipl2015_auction_data.json")` and the data frame loaded and could be parsed with no errors

Comment: Yes, I had  tried the first iteration without the orient flag. It gave me the same error. It turns out there was a problem with my pandas installation. A reinstall fixed the issue.

Comment: cool, I was going to suggest re-downloading the file, but sounds like you found the problem, good job, cheers!

Comment: Ya, I did that too, to be on the safe side. Thanks!

Comment: Good thinking, I would have not thought to re-install pandas :D glad to help!